# Peewee atomic updates complex logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, atomic, peewee

I  need to update fields for a whole users table. It is stated in the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#atomic-updates) that I shouldn't iterate through all table records. But to calculate a new field value I need to perform calculations using loops, user's relations and other complex logic relied on a concrete model.

I tried to include this calculations in the model's property, but I got:

```
peewee.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

**Atomic update:**

```
    query = User.update(balance=(User.balance + User.partners_reward))\
    .where(User.deposit >= 3)
```

**Model:**

```
class User(peewee.Model):
    deposit = peewee.DecimalField(default=0)
    balance = peewee.DecimalField(default=0)

    @property
    def partners(self):
        query = (
            User.select(User, Partnership)
                .join(Partnership, JOIN.INNER, on=Partnership.invited)
                .where(Partnership.referral == self.id)
        )
        partners = query.execute()
        return partners


    @property
    def partners_reward(self):
        partners = self.partners
        sum_reward = 0
        partner_reward = 0.02

        for partner in partners:
            reward = partner.deposit * partner_reward
            sum_reward += reward

        return sum_reward
```

**Prop description:**

Each user has partners (other users invited by him) and depending on them he gets bonuses. So to accomplish the update I need to collect user partners using relations and then calculate the actual bonus using loops.

Changing property to a method solves this, but I don't know how I can get access to a concrete user instance.

So how can some complex logic be implemented in atomic updates or should I do it using loop as not recommended?

Comment: Just a random guess, but perhaps it is expecting a floating point number, 0.0, instead of an integer 0.

Comment: @jdowner Nope, just rechecked: it returns float.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL you are attempting to execute? "complex logic" is not helpful at all to someone trying to help you.

Comment: I've attempted to answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @coleifer That's what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery. If I understand your query example correctly, it's just the sum of each partner deposit * .02?

```
subq = (Partnership
        .select(fn.COALESCE(fn.SUM(Partnership.deposit * .02)))
        .where(Partnership.referral == User.id))
res = (User
       .update(reward=subq)
       .execute())
```

What the above query does is, for each user, it selects all the partnership rows associated with the user, and sums the partnership deposit * .02 and stores the result in the user's "reward" column (assuming such a column existed). The "COALESCE()" bit is to handle the case where a user has no partner, so as to return 0 instead of null.

If you wished to increment the user's balance instead:

```
subq = (Partnership
        .select(fn.COALESCE(fn.SUM(Partnership.deposit * .02)))
        .where(Partnership.referral == User.id))
res = (User
       .update(balance=User.balance + subq)
       .execute())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated the model code so you can see the actual property and added some description about what is going on in the prop. I hope I made everything more clear.

Comment: I know what the property is, but by writing "User.id" e.g., I can get id of each user model for which the update is going to be executed.